# Foreign key constraint are are incompatible

Tags: mysql

I have a problem add FOREIGN KEY

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    userID int NOT NULL,
    username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    personID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Persons(ID)
);
```

The error show:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #3780 - Referencing column 'personID' and referenced column 'ID' in foreign key constraint 'users_ibfk_1' are incompatible.

Comment: [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=025694666535eb722b4a1cb59ac152d6)

Comment: [can't reproduce](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jMbDTq5Q2sdaXHfCmDRn7/0)

Comment: OT: [use password_hash](https://code-boxx.com/password-encrypt-decrypt-php/) for passwords and not plain text.

Comment: Add the output from show create table <table> to the question - check the collation and  charset of the 2 tables, and the engines used.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same name as in the persons table: ID instead of
personID
i.e
Change the column personID in Table users to ID:
personID ==> ID
Then try again to assign the foreign key